# PHP project using mysql database in wampserver

Tags: php, mysql, wampserver, alter

When I am importing my database it displayed me this error:

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`clearancesystem`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-2744_e'>, CONSTRAINT `useraccount_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`SIDNO`) REFERENCES `student` (`SIDNO`))

Comment: Try [disabling the foreign key checks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167141/foreign-keys-and-data-import) on import.

Answer (score 0):

Disable foreign key constraints before starting the import process.

See [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140857/how-to-disable-or-remove-foreign-key-before-importing-database-to-phpmyadmin?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) how to do it by command or GUI

Answer (score 0):

above error is coming due to foreign key constraints.
to come over that error, you need to first disable foreign key constraints and after that do your import task. 
after that you can again set foreign key constraints enable.
**To disable foreign key constraints use below line.**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

**To Enable foreign key constraints use below line.**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```